# What is the list of tags that I can prefix a href with to open specific browsers?

Tags: html, browser, anchor

It is possible to open Microsoft Edge using a "pre-href" tag (my term for it), but I would like to be able to open other browsers as well.  I am unable to find a list of pre-href tags to achieve this.  Ideally, I would like a list that includes Internet Explorer 32bit, 64bit and Google Chrome

As an example, this works for Edge:

```
<a href="microsoft-edge:http://google.com">Open Google in Edge</a>
```

The reason to do this, for my case, is that we are using a product that requires SilverLight support. Our users typically have Chrome as their default, which does not support SilverLight, so when they click a link from an email that references said site, it fails to load.  I would like to format the link to load Internet Explorer.

EDIT:  The environment this will be used in is self-contained and controlled.  I am not proposing this technique be used on the general web, as I can see the problems that would create.  That said, Microsoft has already done this on Bing in an effort to drive Edge adoption. I.e. That horse has already left the barn.
[Example in the wild](https://www.bing.com/search?q=microsoft-edge&qs=n&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=microsoft-edge&sc=8-14&sk=&cvid=660EE94AD09049269F44CA15CE4D3CA7)

Notice the big blue "Open Microsoft Edge".

I feel this is still a valid question, and would appreciate answers.

Comment: this is not advised, majority of users use mobile to browse the web - what mobile uses Edge?

Comment: Wow, [Silverlight is still a thing apparently.](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/07/02/microsoft_silverlight/). The facetious answer to this is, it's 2018, why are you still using silverlight?!

Comment: @Liam yeah was surprised too ^^ why this syntax is still valid is beyond me, down with Microsoft!

Comment: @Liam ... and I wish I could get rid of SilverLight.  The product we use is antiquated for sure and I have been pushing the developer to move it to HTML5.  Not sure if they ever will, so needing other solutions.

Comment: Seems like there is no command for Chrome